# JBoss causing IOException Read Error When Reading from Resource Stream

Tags: jboss5.x, java-io

I get an input stream from a resource as follows:

```
InputStream is = clazz.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(resourcePath);
```

Ultimately this input stream is wrapped in an InputStreamReader and the reader is used with the java.io.LineNumberReader to read lines from a CSV file.

The code works on Tomcat, however when I run the code on a JBoss 5.1.0 GA application server, I get the following exceptions:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Bad file descriptor
    at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:220)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:264)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:306)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:158)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:167)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:136)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:299)
    at java.io.LineNumberReader.readLine(LineNumberReader.java:182)


Caused by: java.io.IOException: Read error
at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:220)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:264)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:306)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:158)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:167)
at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:136)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:299)
at java.io.LineNumberReader.readLine(LineNumberReader.java:182)
```

Does anyone know why this would work on Tomcat but not on JBoss?

Comment: jboss 5 have complicated classloader model, and maybe classloader you're using don't have access to required resources. try different class, for example this.getClass().getClassloader ()

Comment: Yes, that is what I am doing.  The line clazz.getClassLoader() is in a static method in a helper class.  The caller of this method passes its class object via this.getClass().

Comment: @user1516873 If the resource didn't exist or wasn't accessible there would be a `NullPointerException` or a conditional branch away from this code.

Comment: The resource does exist.  I am not seeing a NullPointerException.  I have also tried Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(resourcePath) without any luck.